# Magento 1.9 - Anyone used Voronoy Extra Fees Module?

Tags: module, magento1.9.2.3, extrafee

**Attribute value applied successfully with grand total but attribute not visible on back-end order total https://snipboard.io/JGuBUL.jpg**

I am using this module for extra fees https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee

In the checkout page extra fees field displayed and applied in grand total everything okay, in the order page the extra fees field  not visible, the grand total applied with extra fees but extra fees column not visible, any help thanks.

**The only issue is extra fees field column not visible on backend but frontend its visible during checkout?**

Front-end : https://snipboard.io/fdQN52.jpg

back-end  : https://snipboard.io/JGuBUL.jpg